# How to Develop a get end-point with spring boot that support interruption (pause, connection lost, …)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, get

I'm trying  to develop an endpoint that download files from a server. My endpoint should support interruption (pause, connection lost, …).

For the moment i have no idea how to do it. I just develop a simple get endpoint.

```java
  @GetMapping("/self/{fileName}")
   public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,
                                           @RequestParam(value ="checksum", required = false) String checksumParam,
                                           @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
                                           HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

           Resource resource;
           String contentType = null;
           String country = headers
            .getFirst(fileStorageProperties.getHeaderCountryField())
            .toLowerCase();

           try {

               contentType = request
                 .getServletContext()
                 .getMimeType(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());

           } catch ( IOException ex) {
               this.log.error(ex.getMessage());
           }

           if(contentType == null) {
               contentType = "application/octet-stream";
           }

           HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                responseHeaders
.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"");


               return ResponseEntity.ok()
                       .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                       .headers(responseHeaders)
                       .body(resource);


   }
```

I would like to resume the download from where it was stopped if the download is stopped because of connection lost or if the user choose to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Http header Range? Implement your get method to check for that header and if exists then just cut that number of bytes from your file.